# Are there any physics differences between styles in Mario Maker

Tags: wii-u, super-mario-maker

Mario Maker allows you to change the game style when making levels so that it will look like Super Mario Bros, Super Mario Bros 3, Super Mario World, or New Super Mario Bros. The original games from which these styles originate have noticeable differences in momentum/jump physics. Is there any evidence and/or demonstration that this is not the case with the different styles in Mario Maker?

Answer (score 5):

All styles use the New Super Mario Bros U physics as confirmed by Takashi Tezuka in an interview:

http://nintendoeverything.com/why-super-mario-maker-uses-new-super-mario-bros-u-physics-for-all-game-styles/

However, some styles have bugs not present (or not as easy to pull off) in other styles most likely related to each style's unique abilities for Mario or gameplay characteristics. For example, there was a bug involving being able to jump abnormally high off of springs in the SMW style that people suspected was a result of inertial updates not being made properly while Mario faces forward in between moving from facing left to right.

Comment: Any links describing the bug you mentioned in the last paragraph? Sounds interesting and I'd like to read more about it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they use the physics seen in those games. You can use those physics to your advantage in making a level, so its best to experiment with them all to get the BEST experience for your players.